# How can I send an image from and HTML form to be analyzed by a python AI?

Tags: html, post, server, artificial-intelligence

To dive a bit more in depth, for a Hackathon, a friend and I need to get an image from an HTML form and analyze it using an AI algorithm. We easily handled the HTML form part, but that hard part is sending the image to be analyzed by the algorithm.

How would we do this. Would we have to set the algorithm up on some sort of server and then post the image to it or would we have to somehow integrate the algo into the webpage so it can run there.

Also what frameworks would we need to use and is there a guide to this somewhere?

Thanks,
CantTouchThis

Answer (score 1):

I can't provide you the code because it is a competition, but I can help you a bit:

1. First (if you are using python) make a script that downloads the photo. You have to download the page and parse html document, find your image with regex and download it.. You can use urllib2 for downloading and Beautiful Soup for parsing html file, or, use htmllib to extract all img tags (override do_img), then use urllib2 to download all the images. Make sure everything is inside a definition or method so that we can call it later in our main script.
2. Make sure that the images are saved in your same directory
3. Make the last and main script, first import the first script we have made, and the downloaded file(make sure to give the imports inside a try and except because we haven't downloaded the image yet, you will get a error), call the method or definition of the photo downloading script, then write the rest AI algorithm, tell the file name, after the algorithm executes and gave result, make sure you write a code at the end that deletes the picture, because you might in future be asked to download more images, so you can create a list of websites and use it using a for loop to change the web address in the first script.

Best of Luck!